# Unable to Select First Column of .csv with ADODB in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, adodb

I'm trying to read a .csv from ADODB. Here is a straight copy and paste of a .csv I'm experimenting with:

```
Application Number,Received Date
V222333444,2019-05-05
S222333444,2019-05-05
W222333444,2019-05-05
```

If I select all columns in my SQL then it seems to work:

```
SELECT * FROM `New Data - Rec'd Date.csv`
```

If, however, I specify certain columns (which I will eventually have to do):

```
SELECT [Application Number] FROM `New Data - Rec'd Date.csv`
```

then I seem to be able to select any column **except** the first one. I get a run-time error "No value given for one or more required parameters"  when I try to execute the SQL.

I've tried switching the order of columns and aliasing the .csv but neither worked.

I feel like it might be a problem with how the .csv is formatted, but I originally created it by entering the data in Excel and saving so it shouldn't be. Excel has no problem opening it now. Neither does pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
csv_path = r"C:\Users\User\Google Drive\8 - Coding\1 - VBA work\VAC Appointment Booking\Data\New Data - Rec'd Date.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Might I have to create a schema for ADODB and, if so, what's the easiest way to do that? Is it something else? Thank you in advance.

My full VBA is below:

```
Public Function accessCSV(ByVal strCSVPath As String, _
        ByVal strMasterData As String, _
        ByVal strNewMainData, _
        ByVal strNewEmailData) As ADODB.Recordset
    Application.StatusBar = "Accessing CSVs..."
    Dim strCon As String, strSQL As String

    Dim oConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oTempRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strCSVPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
    oConnection.Open strCon

    strSQL = "SELECT [Application Number] FROM `New Data - Rec'd Date.csv`"

'The line that causes the error
    Set accessCSV = oConnection.Execute(strSQL)
    Set oConnection = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Function
```